# SwipeToDismissBox - detect if releasing would result in a dismiss event

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, jetpack-compose-swipe-to-dismiss

I'm using **material3 1.2.0**.

When using `SwipeToDismissBox` and `rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState` I see a problem, that I can't detect if the user has already swiped far enough to trigger a delete event or if stopping the swipe would simply cancel the swipe delete without any event...

What I want is that the background does change its color as soon as the swipe would result in an action but therefore I need to detect what the result of stopping the swipe would be.

**Code**

Here's my code so far:

```
val deleteValue = SwipeToDismissBoxValue.StartToEnd

val state = rememberSwipeToDismissBoxState(
    confirmValueChange = {
        if (it == deleteValue){
            L.tag("SWIPE-DISMISS").d { "onDelete..." }
            onDelete()
            true
        } else false
    }
)

SwipeToDismissBox(
    modifier = Modifier,
    state = state,
    enableDismissFromEndToStart = false,
    enableDismissFromStartToEnd = true,
    backgroundContent = {
    
        // detect if releasing at the current swipe position would trigger a delete event or not
        // this does not work, it triggers at ~50% of swiping instead of the default threshold of 56dp...
        val success = dismissState.targetValue == deleteValue
        
        val color by animateColorAsState(
            if (success) Color.Red else Color.Transparent,
            label = ""
        )
        
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color)
        ) {
            // ...
        }
    }) {
        content()
    }
```

**Material 1.1.2**

Using the `targetState` did work in the past with `SwipeToDismiss` from material3 1.1.2... For me it seems that the `targetState` is currently broken.

**Solution**

I can solve that manually by using the `56.dp` from `SwipeToDismissBoxDefaults.positionalThreshold` like following to determine my success flag:

```
val minOffset = with(LocalDensity.current) { threshold.toPx() }
val success = dismissState.progress != 0f && abs(dismissState.requireOffset()) > minOffset
```

But I really want to avoid this manual distance checking...